# How do I retrieve a specific value from MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I'm so fed up. I've spent the better part of my free time for the past week trying to figure this out. I know that the query has changed in SQL but I cant figure it out. All of the other posts I can find seem to be outdated. If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

All I am trying to do is retrieve the id of a row by using a unique "passphrase" that I manually entered into a database and then set that as session data so that I can use that data on other pages. I feel like it shouldn't be this hard.

For demostration purposes here is my code using the older mysql_query.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'test321';

$db = 'local_test';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db);  ?>



<?php

include 'includes/connection.php';

$pass = $_POST['inputPass'];

if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "please fill out the form";
    header ('location: user_authenticate.php');
}


$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE pass= '$pass'";

$id = mysql_query($query);


$_SESSION["userId"] = "$id";

print $pass;
print $id;
print $_SESSION["userId"];?>
```

I've tried a lot of things so I've gotten a lot of different errors. I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction here. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So your question is: How can I achieve the same result, but without using the deprecated mysql_* functions?

Comment: I guess he wants to achieve it with deprecated mysql_* functions; already tried with mysql_fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use the `mysql` API; it's deprecated and won't work in PHP 7.

Now that that's out of the way, `mysql_query()` returns a *result set resource* (which is like an object) which can contain *multiple rows* which can contain *multiple columns*. To access the contents of this resource, you have to `fetch` a row into an array and then index into that array for the column you want. You need to do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE pass= '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$id = $row['id'];
```

and then you can use the value of `$id`.

The same holds for `mysqli::query()`, which returns a `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: I wish I understood why this is such a common mistake. There really needs to be a canonical answer for it.